# How to set default status code for a serverless function?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am deploying microservices onto AWS Lambda using serverless. I want to set the default status code as 500 and if the HTTP process succeeds then I want response to have status Code of 200. How to do this? Can this be done through the `serverless.yml` file?

Function:

```
addPermission:
 handler: permissionadd.handler
 events:
  - http:
      path: permission
      method: post
      cors: true
      integration: lambda
      request:
        parameters:
          querystrings:
            companyId: true
            userId: true
```

Comment: Shouldn't your handler code include logic for this? which SDK you are using?

Comment: I don't want the handler to control the status code as javascript errors in the handler will not respond with a status code.

Comment: `as javascript errors in the handler will not respond`: you could use a try/catch where the catch returns code 500. Regarding a default code, I don't know if there is a builtin for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it via serverless.yml.

you can do it from the handler like this:

As it currently stands, any and all lambda invocations that fail and do not specify a particular status code or does not return a response correctly to the API gateway is assumed to be a Http status 500(Internal Server Error).

But assuming you want a custom http code to be returned then you can use somthing like the following:

```
module.exports.my_sample_func = (event, context, callback) ={
    var processed_promise = process_your_event(event_body);

    // define your default response to be returned
    let my_default_response = {
       statusCode:500, // add default faliure http code
       body:JSON.stringify({error: "Some error occured"}),
       headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
    };

    processed_promise.then(function(resolved, rejected){
          // whatever had to be done got completed successfully
          response.statusCode = 200;
          response.body = JSON.stringify({msg: "Processed successfully"});
         callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch(function(rejected){
         callback(response);
    });


}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Additionally, you could also set the a default status as a environment variable in your serverless.yml, and access it in your handler. But you would still have to write some logic your handler neverthless.